# Upload a text file on SVN server using RestSharp (C#)

Tags: c#, svn, upload, restsharp

I use RestSharp to successfully download a text file from a server, using SVN without any problem.
I try now to upload this text file and I do not find the suitable solution (multiple tries without success for now).

Download method:

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

var client = new RestClient(url_path);
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator(usernamee, passwordd);
var fileBytes = client.DownloadData(new RestRequest("#", Method.GET));
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(localPath, "coder_test.output"), fileBytes);
```

Please help me to obtain a code for uploading this file.

What I did try, but unsuccessfully:

```cs
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(local_path);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var content = response.Content;
MessageBox.Show("content: " + content.ToString());
```